# how to call WCF service WebGet method from Angular js script

Tags: c#, angularjs

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetEmployeeA?id={id}")]
    EmployeeA GetEmployeeA(int id);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetEmployeeJSON?str={str}")]
    string GetEmployeeJSON(string str);
}
```

I want to call the above methods using angularJS script... I tried httpget() with param:

```
$http({ url: yourURL, method: "GET", params: {: params:" ''} });
```

Comment: i want to call the above methods using angularJS script...I tried httpget() with param

Comment: $http({ url: yourURL, method: "GET", params: {: params:" ''} });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the concrete problem? If you do it like this, it should work just fine:

```
$http({
    url: "http://yourURL/GetEmployeeA", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {id: 123}
});
```

resp.

```
$http({
    url: "http://yourURL/GetEmployeeJSON", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {str: 'foo'}
});
```

Comment: khlr sir please tell me is there any angularJs specific  library required for that or its work with /angular.min.js library

Comment: This is part of the regular AngularJS library. Here, have a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: sir its working but result is obtained only if we use internet explorer, but for other browsers its does not show anything..